# Differential form heat kernel on hyperbolic space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, heat-equation

Is there an explicit formula in the literature for the heat kernel of the Hodge Laplacian on differential forms?

I found some on functions, but not on forms of higher degree.

What at least about 1-forms on the hyperbolic plane?

Comment: There is a formula for the heat kernel of Hodge Laplacian on noncompact type semisimple symmetric space $G/K$, given by Harish-Chandra. The formula is written down by Plancherel density, which is explicit for the hyperbolic space $SO_0(n,1)/SO(n)$. Maybe this formula is not very explicit as what you want, but enough for some applications. See theorem 2.2 in http://www.math.uiuc.edu/documenta/vol-07/11.pdf